# C# RegEx a value between numbers and characters?

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I want to search for the first occurrence of a specific string and capture a value between a set length of numbers and characters that change.

Using Nate Barbettini’s https://dotnetfiddle.net/vhkUV5 example I butchered it into doing what I almost need, it won’t compile and from what I’ve seen my RegEx is way off so I defiantly need help with it.

In my example I want to find the first occurrence of the PID value “116c” for chrome.exe and not all three PID values.  What’s the best way to get one PID value?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var output = @"
        0a80    6e 6f 74 65 70 61 64 2b  2b 2e 65 78 65 20 20 20   notepad++.exe
        0a90    50 49 44 3d 31 64 38 63  7c 30 37 35 36 34 0d 0a   PID=1d8c|07564..
        0aa0    6a 68 69 5f 73 65 72 76  69 63 65 2e 65 78 20 20   jhi_service.ex
        0ab0    50 49 44 3d 31 38 64 34  7c 30 36 33 35 36 0d 0a   PID=18d4|06356..
        0ac0    4c 4d 53 2e 65 78 65 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   LMS.exe
        0ad0    50 49 44 3d 31 63 36 38  7c 30 37 32 37 32 0d 0a   PID=1c68|07272..
        0ae0    63 6d 64 2e 65 78 65 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   cmd.exe
        0af0    50 49 44 3d 30 66 37 38  7c 30 33 39 36 30 0d 0a   PID=0f78|03960..
        0b00    63 6f 6e 68 6f 73 74 2e  65 78 65 20 20 20 20 20   conhost.exe
        0b10    50 49 44 3d 30 62 64 30  7c 30 33 30 32 34 0d 0a   PID=0bd0|03024..
        0b20    76 63 74 69 70 2e 65 78  65 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   vctip.exe
        0b30    50 49 44 3d 31 38 30 38  7c 30 36 31 35 32 0d 0a   PID=1808|06152..
        0b40    63 68 72 6f 6d 65 2e 65  78 65 20 20 20 20 20 20   chrome.exe
        0b50    50 49 44 3d 31 31 36 63  7c 30 34 34 36 30 0d 0a   PID=116c|04460..
        0b60    63 68 72 6f 6d 65 2e 65  78 65 20 20 20 20 20 20   chrome.exe
        0b70    50 49 44 3d 31 36 39 34  7c 30 35 37 38 30 0d 0a   PID=1694|05780..
        0b80    63 68 72 6f 6d 65 2e 65  78 65 20 20 20 20 20 20   chrome.exe
        0b90    50 49 44 3d 31 30 62 30  7c 30 34 32 37 32 0d 0a   PID=10b0|04272..";

        var regex = new Regex(@"chrome.exe[\s].................................................................(.*)........");  

        var resultList = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(output))
        {
            resultList.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
        }

        var pid = string.Join(", ", resultList);

        Console.WriteLine(pid);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
116c, 1694, 10b0
```

I’m extremely new so any help or pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var regex = new Regex("chrome\\.exe\\s*.*PID=(.*)\\|");

var pid = regex.Matches(output)
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(match => match.Groups[1].ToString())
               .First();
```

You can test the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/eUYgjo/2).

Comment: Damian, that solution works beautifully!!  Thank you